# default at the beginning of switch block

Tags: c++, coding-style

While going through the code for parser, e.g. Parser.cpp inside clang/Parse directory of clang compiler

```
switch (Close) {
default: break;
case tok::r_paren : LHSName = "("; DID = diag::err_expected_rparen; break;
case tok::r_brace : LHSName = "{"; DID = diag::err_expected_rbrace; break;
case tok::r_square: LHSName = "["; DID = diag::err_expected_rsquare; break;
case tok::greater:  LHSName = "<"; DID = diag::err_expected_greater; break;
case tok::greatergreatergreater:
                    LHSName = "<<<"; DID = diag::err_expected_ggg; break;
}
```

I see that the `default` is at the beginning. Is there any reason for keeping it that way. Usually we keep the `default` at the end so I am a bit confused.

Comment: I don't believe it matters, in fact if your default block isn't doing anything anyway you can omit it entirely.

Comment: @RichardPennington: Might that not seriously be a reason? I understood there can indeed be a performance advantage in putting the most frequently use cases first. For example, see http://books.google.com/books?id=3JfE7TGUwvgC&lpg=PT571&ots=RQs-4K9P9G&dq=switch%20most%20frequent%20case%20first&pg=PT571#v=onepage&q=switch%20most%20frequent%20case%20first&f=false

Comment: A compiler has several options when generating a switch statement and usually choice the best one for the cases. For example, a lot of consecutive cases, e.g. 1, 2, 3, ... would be generated into a jump table, while a sparse set of cases (1, 200, 1000) would probably be done with the equivalent of if ... else if ... In that second case, then the earlier cases might be more efficient. I wouldn't count on it, though.

Comment: I agree with @Fred Larson's view. It seems like we can get some performance advantage while using the most frequent use cases first.

Answer (score 1):

The order makes no differences, as long as you have included your `break`s.

As an aside, I like to put the `break` immediately *before* every `case` or `default`. It's much easier to verify this rule has been followed than to try to look ahead to the end of each case statement.

```
switch (Close) {
  break; default:
  break; case tok::r_paren : LHSName = "("; DID = diag::err_expected_rparen;
  break; case tok::r_brace : LHSName = "{"; DID = diag::err_expected_rbrace;
  break; case tok::r_square: LHSName = "["; DID = diag::err_expected_rsquare;
  break; case tok::greater:  LHSName = "<"; DID = diag::err_expected_greater;
  break; case tok::greatergreatergreater: LHSName = "<<<"; DID = diag::err_expected_ggg;
}
```

You might find this easier to understand if you interpret `break` to mean *"Don't fall through **into** this case from any other case."* instead of *"Don't fall through **from** this case into any succeeding case."*

In this layout, it is very easy to see if a `break` is missing, and therefore forcing the writer (and the reader) to ask him/herself "do I want a follow-through here?". All the `break`s line up nicely, and it's very obvious if one is missing.

Clarification: There is no 'magic' in my answer. I'm just placing my whitespace in a manner that is much more readable to me. And whitespace doesn't matter, therefore I'm free to do this. A `break` at the very end of the `switch` is redundant. If missing, the compiler is not allowed to loop around to the top of the `switch`, as if it was some kind of `while` loop. Equally, a redundant `break` at the very start of a `switch` changes nothing, and must be accepted (and ignored) by the compiler.

Comment: Not sure that makes it any clearer. What about first statement that does not look legal. And What about the last case it does not have a break. It also makes moving the cases statements around more difficult as have to make a note weather the next line has a break or not.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I'm pretty sure that a `break` at the end is always redundant, and therefore it is not incorrect to leave it off. Also, the break at the start is redundant also. I've never seen g++ complain about this - maybe it's an extension. I better look it up now. As a result, there is no difficulty in moving lines around - every line, without exception, will have a `break` at the start - that makes things very easy.

Comment: If the syntax causes questions for the people reading it, then it's not really any clearer. ;-]

Comment: :-) @ildjarn. It makes it easier for me to read my own code. And I might be the only person that ever reads my code :-/  Even if I don't convince everyone to use this, I'd be happy if I could verify it is compliant with the standard.

Comment: By my reading of C++11 §6.4 it does appear to be standard-compliant; the `break;` outside of any `case`/`default` label is simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I see the position of a default matter is when doing something like this, which is a [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) type construct and should probably never be attempted on modern platforms. :)

```
void copyAligned4Bytes(u32 *in, u32 *out, int numBytes)
{
  assert((numBytes & 0x03) == 0);

  while(numBytes)
  {
    switch(numBytes)
    {
      default: *out++ = *in++; numBytes -= 4;
      case 12: *out++ = *in++; numBytes -= 4;
      case 8: *out++ = *in++; numBytes -= 4;
      case 4: *out++ = *in++; numBytes -= 4;
    }
  }
}
```

Ah, the joys of coding in C as closer to assembler as possible to get a certain type of jump table.

Comment: Also see Intel's [Branch and Loop Reorganization to Prevent Mispredicts](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/branch-and-loop-reorganization-to-prevent-mispredicts). It tells you to make the dominant case the first one. I've got a `default` dominating the other two cases by about 100:1.